# Unable to configure buildFlag for gopls with mason

Tags: neovim, mason

I'm using kickstart on my vanilla Neovim config and having some troubles with configuring `buildFlags` for my `gopls`. I added uncommented `gopls` and added following config in my `init.lua` Spent few hours already and no idea why it's not added.

```lua
    local servers = {
      -- clangd = {},
      gopls = {
        buildFlags = { '-tags=integration' }, 
      },
      -- pyright = {},
      -- rust_analyzer = {},
      -- tsserver = {},
      -- html = { filetypes = { 'html', 'twig', 'hbs'} },

      lua_ls = {
        Lua = {
          workspace = { checkThirdParty = false },
          telemetry = { enable = false },
        },
      },
    }
```